# Ubuntu Studio 22.04 - Carla plugin refresh does not work

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-studio

A brand new install of Ubuntu Studio 22.04. As the header says, even this version have the plugins refresh problem in Carla (2.4.2) mentioned earlier. So I enabled the backports where there seems to available Carla version 2.5.6. This also shows in the Muon Carla version list. But because of some reason Muon does not allow me to update to the new version of Carla. Any ideas for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good way to solve this problem but... Instead of using Muon, I first installed Synaptic. By utilising this it was possible to do the forced update from 2.4.2 to 2.5.6. Synaptic gave as well some nasty warnings but did the job. In addition to the main carla-package I updated also a few other carla-related packages. Now it seems that Carla is working in a proper way and co-operates e.g. with QjackCtl.